# How do duels work in Reigns?

Tags: reigns

When in a duel I can attack, which moves me forwards, and defend, which moves me backwards. If I defend, sometimes I can use a "special" move on the next turn. However, I can't seem to consistently deal (or avoid) damage regardless of the combinations of moves I make.

**How do I win a duel?**

Answer (score 2):

I also couldn't find any duelling guide online ([appunwrapper](http://www.appunwrapper.com/category/reigns/) has some major findings on Reigns).

That said, I suspect that it is a combination of **anticipating** what your enemy is going to do (attacking vs defending) and with the two, somewhat random moves you get, trying to hit them **in the exact position** (the little bullet points under the fighters) where they will be.

Often, it will pay off to defend first (play more defensively) and use the **special move** you often get afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I tried various tactics on this and I think I came to a conclusion that the two dots in the middle are the ones you should always try to land on/end your turns on. Whenever you're hit on them, you don't get killed.